# Issue writing .csv file with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am having an issue writing a `.csv` file with PHP with a returned array from the a mysql database.

```
Array ( [item_id] => technology-15 [name] => Blue Rocks [owner] => Bob Test)
```

Here is what my code to write the `.csv` looks like.

```
$filename = "documents/results.csv";

$heading = array ("Item ID'", "'Name'", "'Owner'");

$data = results_excel (); //returns the array shown above.

$fp = fopen ($filename, "w");
fputcsv ($fp, $heading);//works

foreach ($data as $field) {
    print_r($data);
    fputcsv ($fp, $field);
}

fclose ($fp);
```

Can anyone shed some light on why it's not writting the array data in to my `.csv`? Also please note that the `$heading` does get written in to the `.csv` so it's not a write permission issue.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: How many rows does `results_excel()` return?  Are you sure you didn't want to do `fputcsv ($fp, $data);`?

Comment: Why not simply use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)?